# add parameter to get_queryset request in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `Django 2.0` and `Django REST Framework`.

I have two models in **contacts** app

**contacts/models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default='')


class ContactPhoneNumber(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone
```

**contacts/serializers.py**

```
class ContactPhoneNumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactPhoneNumber
        fields = ('id', 'phone', 'primary', 'created', 'modified')
```

and **contacts/views.py**

```
class ContactPhoneNumberViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ContactPhoneNumberSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ContactPhoneNumber.objects.filter(
            contact__user=self.request.user
        )
```

**urls.py**

```
router.register(r'contact-phone', ContactPhoneNumberViewSet, 'contact_phone_numbers')
```

What I want is following endpoints

- **GET:** `/contact-phone/{contact_id}/` *list phones numbers of particular contact*
- **POST:**`/contact-phone/{contact_id}/` *add phone numbers to particular contact*
- **PUT:** `/contact-phone/{contact_phone_number_id}/` *update particular phone number*
- **DELETE:** `/contact-phone/{contact_phone_number_id}/` *delete particular phone number*

**`PUT` and `Delete` can be achieved as default action of `ModelViewSet` but how to make `get_queryset` to accept `contact_id` as required parameter?**

> Edit 2

I followed doc [Binding ViewSets to URLs explicitly](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#binding-viewsets-to-urls-explicitly)

update **app/urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'contacts', ContactViewSet, 'contacts')
contact_phone_number_view_set = ContactPhoneNumberViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list/<contact_pk>/',
    'post': 'create/<contact_pk>/',
    'put': 'update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
})
router.register(r'contact-phone-number', contact_phone_number_view_set, 'contact_phone_numbers')

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

But it is giving error

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add extra actions to the viewset using [`@action`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) decorator:

```
class ContactPhoneNumberViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ContactPhoneNumberSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ContactPhoneNumber.objects.filter(
            contact__user=self.request.user
        )

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
    def add_to_contact(self, request, contact_id=None):
        contact = Contact.objects.get(id=contact_id)
        serializer = ContactPhoneNumberSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(contact=contact)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def set_password(self, request, contact_id=None):
        contact = Contact.objects.get(id=contact_id)
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(contact.contactphonenumber_set.all(), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**UPD**

Since you don't need additional actions, you can override `retrieve` and `create` defaults methods:

```
class ContactPhoneNumberViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = ContactPhoneNumberSerializer

        def get_queryset(self):
            return ContactPhoneNumber.objects.filter(
                contact__user=self.request.user
            )

        def create(self, request, pk=None):
            contact = Contact.objects.get(id=contact_id)
            serializer = ContactPhoneNumberSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save(contact=contact)
                return Response(serializer.data)
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors,
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
            contact = Contact.objects.get(pk=pk)
            serializer = PasswordSerializer(contact.contactphonenumber_set.all(), many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

To change standard `create` url use explicitly url binding:

```
contact_list = ContactPhoneNumberViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create',
    'put': 'update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
})

urlpatterns = [
    path('api//contact-phone/<int:pk>/', contact_list, name='contact-list'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: then I would have to disable `get_queryset` and `create` methods, because I do not want to list all phone numbers at once.

Also I want clean URL without adding extra action. can't I pass required additional parameter to `get_querset`?

Comment: @AnujTBE Not sure, but I think it's impossible. The problem is you need somehow to deside inside `get_queryset` method if selected `kwarg` was `contact_phone_number_id` or `contact_id`. But without extra actions you cannot distinguish them.

Comment: distinguishing is based on request methods. with request methods `GET` and `POST` **contact_id** will be passed and with rest **contact_phone_number_id** will be passed.

Comment: @AnujTBE, Ah, yes it makes sense. I missed it. Probably binding viewset explicitly can help you also, check this part of the docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#binding-viewsets-to-urls-explicitly  Sorry dont have any other ideas at this time.

Comment: please see `Edit 2`

Comment: is there any way I can take `api` urls outside of `urlpatterns`. There should be only `api/` in the `urlpatterns` others outside

Comment: @AnujTBE you can create separate `urls2.py` file, add there `path('contact-phone/<int:pk>/', contact_list, name='contact-list'),`. And include it to the main urls.py: `path('apu/', include('urls2')),`. See this doc for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171371/discussion-between-anuj-tbe-and-neverwalkaloner).

Comment: Thanks for your help. used your first answer by defining extra action.

Comment: can I pass `many=True` so that I could create multiple `phone_number` object? It's working fine for single object.

Comment: @AnujTBE I suppose it should work. Just pass with request list of objects and add many=True to serializer: `serializer = ContactPhoneNumberSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)`

Comment: Thanks. One more little help needed. Can I pass extra `kwargs` to the action so that I could implement `update` and `delete` methods on `phone_numbers` in the same `ViewSet` instead of writing a separate `ViewSet` like `url/contact/<contact_pk>/delete_phone/<phone_pk>/`

Comment: @AnujTBE Don't have chance to test it. Try to use action's url_path argument like this: `@action(methods=['post'], detail=False, url_path='delete_phone/<phone_pk>/')`.

Comment: I tried, but it gives `page not found` error. You can see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50425262/3719167 for more detail