# Django REST Framework - pass extra parameter to actions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `Django 2.0` and `Django REST Framework`

I have created an action method to delete particular object from database

**contacts/views.py**

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, AdminAuthenticationPermission,)

    # others actions goes here

    @action(methods=['delete'], detail=False, url_path='delete_phone/<phone_pk>/')
    def delete_phone(self, request, pk=None):
        contact = self.get_object()
        print(contact)
        print(pk)
        print(self.kwargs['phone_pk'])
        return Response({'status': 'success'})
```

**apps/urls.py**

```
router.register(r'contacts', ContactViewSet, 'contacts')

api_urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

But when I access

```
DELETE: http://url/api/contacts/delete_phone/1/
```

**It gives `page not found` error.**

In the error page, there is listing in *tried url patterns*

```
api/ ^contacts/delete_phone/<phone_pk>//$ [name='contacts-delete-phone']
api/ ^contacts/delete_phone/<phone_pk>\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='contacts-delete-phone']
```

Comment: It might be because the way it's defined it's currently expecting a `/` at the end. Try with it and see if that works?

Comment: sorry for the fault. `/` is already there in url. It was a typo here. Updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved the problem using [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers)

For those who need it, install the plugin and configure `urls.py`

```
from rest_framework_nested import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'contacts', ContactViewSet, 'contacts')
contact_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'contacts', lookup='contact')
contact_router.register(r'phone_number', ContactPhoneNumberViewSet, base_name='contact-phone-numbers')

api_urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('', include(contact_router.urls))
]
```

Comment: Did you made a new viewset for delete phone action```ContactPhoneNumberViewSet``` but as in question you have formed in that can we do the following using the same viewset ```ContactViewSet```?@Anuj

Answer (score 82):

In case you can't/don't want/whatever install `drf-nested-routers`, you could achieve the same by doing:

```
@action(detail=True,
        methods=['delete'],
        url_path='contacts/(?P<phone_pk>[^/.]+)')
def delete_phone(self, request, phone_pk, pk=None):
    contact = self.get_object()
    phone = get_object_or_404(contact.phone_qs, pk=phone_pk)
    phone.delete()
    return Response(.., status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

The trick is to put the regex in `url_path` parameter of the decorator and pass it to the decorated method (avoid using just `pk` or it will collide with the first pk)

Tested with:

```
Django==2.0.10
djangorestframework==3.9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this has changed since this question was asked, but this works for me in REST Framework 3.13.

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=False, url_path='my_action/(?P<my_pk>[^/.]+)')
def my_action(self, request, my_pk=None):
    return Response()
```

Resulting in the following entry in urlconf

```
^my_viewset/my_action/(?P<my_pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='my-viewset-my-action']
```